# Printing a \pageref{} but only when not on that page in LaTeX

Tags: conditionals

I would like to set up a macro to print a page reference with a reference, but only when the label is not on the same page.

For example, I'm looking to define \myref{} so that this code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newcommand{\myref}[1]{Table~\ref{#1} (magic happens here) on page~\pageref{#1}}
\begin{document}
\label{firstpage}
\lipsum[1]
\pagebreak
\label{secondpage}
\lipsum[2]
\myref{firstpage}\\
\myref{secondpage}
\end{document}
```

This should print something like

```
Table 1 on page 1
Table 2
```

I've searched for something like this, I apologize if I didn't find the duplicate that's out there.

Answer (score 2):

Of course I find an answer right *after* I post the question, but it looks like the [varioref](http://ftp.math.purdue.edu/mirrors/ctan.org/macros/latex/required/tools/varioref.pdf) package is what I was after.  I would be interested in ways to do it directly if they exist, but at this point it's mostly just out of curiosity to see how it would be done.